# Sonar is showing new violations in old code

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are using Sonar Qube 6.7.3 and sonar-java-plugin 5.3

We have made below changes to our sonar configuration recently

1. Enabled new rules
2. Changed configuration to include byte code(changed from 'clean sonar:sonar' to 'clean package sonar:sonar')

We are using sonar svn plugin and provide valid credentials to it.

I understand providing byte code to sonar will help it identify more issues but, I **expect Sonar to flag new issues based on svn code commit date and last analysis date, but it is not**.

Please let me know why it is flagging issues in old code as new?

Comment: If you enabled new rules then it will flag violations of those new rules in all code base not just in commits made after activation

Comment: yes, it will show violations in old code, but will not label them as new violations I believe. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: From below thread I understand the new issues caused because of providing class files to sonar.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/oEw61qJYR6M

But I could not understand why sonar is showing new errors in old code. Because it can get the code committed date from svn.

Also help me find a way to handle this new issues. I dont want to break my build because of these issues from old code.

Comment: `But I could not understand why sonar is showing new errors in old code` why should it scan only code committed after changes in config/rule set instead of scanning all code?  `Also help me find a way to handle this new issues` you haven't even posted those issues. But there are two options anyway: change build config back or change your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sonar Sanner always scans the entire code base. If somebody has decided that some code structures are wrong or dangerous (the ruleset have been changed) then SonarQube has to notify about all occurrences of that code. Why? Let's think about the following example:

After a plugin upgrade, SonarQube provides a new very important security rule which forbids the use of a dangerous cipher algorithm. Now is the question:

- is it only dangerous in new code?
- is it always dangerous?

Of course, it is always dangerous. SonarQube doesn't force you to fix everything (usage of the quality gates is optional). Its main goal is to let you know how many problems (code smells/bugs/vulnerabilities) exist in the whole code base.

Comment: Is there any possibility to configure, to consider only new code changes to scan and find the problems? or Is there any possibility to generate the report which is reported between the date range?

Comment: SonarScanner always scan all code. If you use SonarQube paid version (Developer+) or SonarCloud then you are able to analyze [branches](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/branches/overview/) and [pull requests](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/pull-request/). SonarQube will present only a diff between the main branch and new branch / pull request.

Comment: Thanks, @agabrys for your prompt response. We are using SonarQube and the problem is, we are working on a very old project and if I modify one line of code from the file which has around more than 1000 lines, SonarQube is scanning all lines of code in the same file and showing the list of problems which are even not related to my modifications. Please suggest to me if any possibility is there to configure only a currently modified line of code than scanning the entire file.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer and previous comment: `SonarScanner always scan the entire code base`. You cannot change it. It is impossible to scan only new lines.