# Sonarqube old code smell is showing in new code

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, code-analysis

I am working on Sonarqube 6.4 for analysing issues that have come after a specific date in the new code but it shows issues (more specifically code smells) which are there in very old files. I want to implement this as we are trying to catch only the new errors created by developers during git push.

Here is the Quality gate that I am using for each project:
[Sonar quality gate settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhAYd.png)

Github status for last modification on this file:
[Git status for last modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyP31.png)

Sonar showing code smell occured 3 days ago: [Sonarqube issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mNtq.png)

Leak period settings:[Leak period settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KoKA.png)

I am not able to understand why this code smell issue is coming now when this file has not been modified since months.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51504588/sonar-is-showing-new-violations-in-old-code) SO question. Maybe someone has updated a plugin or changed the rule settings. Please also plan to upgarde to 7.9 LTS.

Comment: I am unable to upgrade because this is the one we use through the whole organization. And also, if Sonarqube scans the entire code, why doesn't it shows me all the errors?

Comment: No update in rules and quality profile has been made by anybody.

Comment: You might get a better answer at the SonarQube Community Forum: https://community.sonarsource.com/

Comment: Anybody figured out why this is happening?

Comment: Upgrade sonarqube to the latest stable version. THat might resolve the issue